# Grid of buttons: Change color of one when it is clicked

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have a grid of buttons I've created like this (using Tkinter on Python 3.4):

```
from tkinter import *

vText = [ "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J" ]
boat  = [ "A1","A2","A3" ]
shots = []

def press( pos, b, pos2 ):
    if pos in shots:
        print( "You've chosen this already!" )
    else:
        shots.append( pos )
        if pos in boat:
            print( "Hit!" )
            b[pos2].configure( bg = "red", fg = "white" )
        else:
            print( "Miss." )
            b[pos2].configure( bg = "blue", fg = "white" )

root   = Tk()
button = []
row    = []
column = []
for a in range( 1, 102 ):
    button.append( a )
    row.append(    a )
    column.append( a )

for i in range( 0, 10 ):
    for j in range( 1, 11 ):
        p2 = i * 10 + j
        button[p2] = Button( root, text    = vText[i] + str(j),                   \
                                   command = lambda i=i, j=j, position=vText[i] + str(j): press( position, button, p2 ), \
                                   padx    = 25,                                  \
                                   pady    = 25,                                  \
                                   bg      = "#66CCCC"                            \
                                   )
        button[p2].grid( row = i, column = j )

root.wm_title( "Enemy grid" )
root.mainloop()
```

As you can see, I've tried (in the **`press()`** definition ) to do the job, but `pos2` only is able to reference the last one because it uses `i` and `j` in the `for` loops.

This is part of a BattleShip code, so there are a few bits and pieces I've added since this. However, the question is the same. I want to be able to click one, and have it change color when it is clicked. It needs to be possible for all 100 buttons created. Additionally, I need it to become red if it is on a hit, or blue if it is a miss.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is not enough code here to really make any sort of recommendations.  You did not show us your binding code, so we have literally nothing to work with.

Comment: @Tritium21 Will edit to show more code. Thanks.

Comment: @Tritium21 My entire code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for buttons in Tkinter (or any GUI framework, though the terms and techniques will very), you need to bind a function to the button.

For example:

```
from functools import partial

def my_func_name(sequence, index):
    widget = sequence[index]
    widget.configure(bg='white') #  for example

for i in range(0,10):
    for j in range(1,11):
        p2 = i * 10 + j
        par = partial(my_func_name, button, p2)
        button[p2] = Button(root, text = vText[i] + str(j), command=par, padx=25, pady=25, bg = "#66CCCC")
        button[p2].grid(row=i, column=j)
```

[Effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) wrote a pretty good book on Tkinter (free), there is also [Tkdocs](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/concepts.html#events), which is a wonderful tutorial that covers the basics in more detail than is fitting of an SO question.

This answer has been edited to reflect a boneheaded gaff I made when I first answered the question.

Comment: I've never worked with binding (or even heard of it; I'm very new to tkinter). What do I put in the <'1'> spot?

Comment: '<1>' is the string representing a left mouse click (primary mouse click if you have your OS configured to swap mouse buttons).  It is meant to be used literally, as-is.

Comment: Problem is that I might need two arguments to my_func_name; I need to make it red or blue.

Comment: You can do a few things for that; you can either pass a partial into the callback (``pydoc functools.partial`` in your shell), or you can use the widget in the event object to lookup and dispatch another function.

Comment: I've literally been working with tkinter for 24 hours now, so I don't completely understand that. I'll do some reading on the Effbot book as well as on Tkdocks. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Welcome to event driven programming.  It is a steep learning curve at first, but levels off quickly.  Just keep reading, keep googleing, and it will start to come naturally.  Now you at least know you have to bind events to widgets.

Comment: You normally should _not_ use `bind` on a button. You should use the `-command` attribute. Otherwise you lose some of the features of the button, such as being able to be used with keyboard navigation. You also lose some subtle UI behavior.

Comment: @Tritium21 and BryanOakley Got it to work with a few if statements. Thank you for all your help!